# Lost in trying to understand this Struct in coding problem

Tags: c++

I have a small coding problem which involves finding the largest subsquare in a square matrix surrounded by 0's given a matrix of '0's and '1's.

I understand the algorithm to compute that max subsquare problem. However I am having trouble understanding the source code. The struct is creating the square, and I am confused as to what the statements and variables in the struct (such as `size_`, `data_`, etc) mean.

Moreover, the `Square s` in the `main()` function is provided using `struct Square`, so I have to understand how this struct is working before I can work with `Square s` to find the largest subsquare in the square matrix.

I am also unsure as to how to read in the values of the matrix `Square s` in the format it is given. I would like to use a 2D array representation instead.

To understand what `outRow` and `outCol` and `outSize` mean in `findSquare()`, I've tried printing them out using `cout`, but I am getting the values 4197501, 0, and 0 respectively. I have no idea why or how.

```
/******************************************************************************
Given a square matrix with values representing pixel colors black (0) and
white (1), implement a function that finds the largest subsquare with all four
borders filled with black pixels. The function should compute three values:
row and column of the top left corner of the subsquare, and its side length.
If no such subsquare exists, the return side length should be set to 0.

Note:
     - Do not change 'findSquare' function signature.
******************************************************************************/

#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Square is defined as follows:

struct Square
{
public:
    explicit Square(size_t size) : size_(size), data_(new int[size * size])
    { }

    Square(std::initializer_list<int> init) : size_(init.size()), data_()
    {
        size_ = std::sqrt(init.size());
        if (init.size() != (size_ * size_))
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not enough initializer elements to complete the square");

        data_.reset(new int[size_ * size_]);
        std::move(std::begin(init), std::end(init), &data_[0]);
    }

    int& operator()(size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if (row >= size_ || col >= size_)
            throw std::out_of_range("OOB");

        return data_[size_ * row + col];
    }

    const int& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const
    {
        if (row >= size_ || col >= size_)
            throw std::out_of_range("OOB");

        return data_[size_ * row + col];
    }

    size_t Size() const { return size_; }

private:
    size_t size_;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> data_;
};

void findSquare(const Square& square, size_t& outRow, size_t& outCol, size_t& outSize)
{
    // your code here

    // My code. Trying to understand what outRow, outCol, and outSize represent
    cout << "This is row: " << outRow << '\n';
    cout << "This is col: " << outCol << '\n';
    cout << "This is size: " << outSize << '\n';

}

int main()
{
        Square s
        {
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 1, 1, 0
        };

    size_t row, col, size;

    findSquare(s, row, col, size);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`outRow` `outCol` and `outSize` are *output parameters*. They have no meaning when the function is called (which is why you get garbage values). They are there for you to assign to when you've calculated the result.

```
outSize = size of largest subsquare
outRow = row of largest subsquare
outCol = column of largest subsquare
```

As for the implementation of `Square` is just a square 2D matrix, you don't have to understand how it works, just understand how to use it. It uses `operator()` for indexing and a method `Size` for the size. So you might write something like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < square.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < square.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout << square(i, j);
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

to print out a `Square` and something like

```
size_t size;
cin >> size;
Square square(size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        cin >> square(i, j);
    }
}
```

to read in a `Square`.

Comment: If I were to try to copy over the elements of Square s into an array square[][] of the same dimensions, could I use a similar approach? I have an idea for finding the largest subsquare, but it involves doing some operations on an array.

Comment: @AkashL You don't need "an array square[][] of the same dimensions" to do any operation. Given a `Square s;`, just use `s(i,j)` where you would use `a[i][j]` if `a` were an array. That's what john is trying to say. On the other hand, if you are going to modify that class, just note that it store the matrix as a 1D array `data_` of `size_ = size * size` elements.

Comment: @AkashL Not sure how to say it any plainer. `Square` gives you all the operations you need. Why would your professor have given it to you otherwise? What is it you think an array would have that `Square` does not?